# Docker how to recompile jar file with maven

Tags: java, docker, maven

I am new to docker, and I am trying to setup docker for spring boot project.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build
WORKDIR usr/src/springboot
COPY . ./
RUN mvn install
RUN mvn clean package 
#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim 
ARG JAR_NAME="springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
WORKDIR /usr/src/springboot
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build /usr/src/springboot/target/${JAR_NAME}.jar ./springboot.jar
CMD ["java","-jar", "./springboot.jar"]
```

Which works completely fine and I can access hello world from localhost:8080

But my confusion is how to make any changes in java file reflect in the docker container? how do I recompile the .jar file.

I tried something like `docker exec -it strange_shaw "mvn clean package"`

But it throws error `exec: "mvn clean package": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: It does not make sense to first all `install` and then `clean package`

Comment: try mvn clean install

Comment: Only a `mvn verify` is enough. Apart from that is the question: Do you need to  build within the container? I would suggest to build outside the container (is simply faster) and just copy the final jar into the container. Furthermore you can configure `<build><finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>..` and you get always `target/aname` without the version which simplifies coopying into the container...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I want to build outside the container. What is the command to do that?

Comment: `mvn clean verify`?

Answer (score 0):

when you are ***using double FROM*** instruction inside your Dockerfile , ***Docker will keep only the latest FROM*** and use the previous FROM to build the next one.

So it is simple to find this error because **FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build** only used to build the next step **FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim** and will be removed from the final image(this strategy used to minimize the docker image size).

I hope that give you a clear idea about Dockerfile with  multiple stage.

Comment: So how do I declare maven then?

Comment: you need to do that only inside the first stage before the second FROM .

Comment: If i make any changes in java file, I shouldn't be recreating the entire image again, that does not make sense to me. I just want to recompile jar file with maven and copy it into the container. So what changes do i need to do in dockerfile?

Comment: yes if you build the jar file outside using your IDE (intellij,eclipse) you can just  keep the package stage :

Comment: You need to rebuild the entire image, in the same way you need to rebuild the entire `.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

Build your jar outside after your Dockerfile will be like that:

```sh
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim 
ARG JAR_NAME="springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
WORKDIR /usr/src/springboot
EXPOSE 8080
COPY /usr/src/springboot/target/${JAR_NAME}.jar ./springboot.jar
CMD ["java","-jar", "./springboot.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that maven was not installed within the container. So I changed my Dockerfile to

```
FROM openjdk:11
ARG JAR_NAME="springboot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
WORKDIR /usr/src/springboot
EXPOSE 8080
#COPY --from=build /usr/src/springboot/target/${JAR_NAME}.jar ./springboot.jar
#CMD ["java","-jar", "./springboot.jar"]
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install curl -y

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.3

# 2- Define a constant with the working directory
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"

# 4- Define the URL where maven can be downloaded from
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

# 5- Create the directories, download maven, validate the download, install it, remove downloaded file and set links
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && echo "Downloading maven" \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  \
  && echo "Unziping maven" \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  \
  && echo "Cleaning and setting links" \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

# 6- Define environmental variables required by Maven, like Maven_Home directory and where the maven repo is located
ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
```

This will install maven inside the container and set $PATH

```
docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/springboot -p 8080:8080 spring-boot-app
```

Run above command to start container and map your project folder to container folder and local port to container port. So both are in sync if you do any changes in project.

```
docker exec -it <container_name> mvn verify
```

Above command will create the .jar file. Restart the container.

```
docker exec -it <container_name> java -jar target/<file_name>.jar
```

Will execute the jar file in port 8080 and will be accessible in your localhost:8080